# Limiting what a user can see

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I've got a TFS server in which team projects exists. These team projects have area paths below them. These area paths represents projects of certain customers. We want to give customers access to their area path.

The problem is when we do that they automatically gain access to all other area paths withing that team project. Is there a way of limiting access so the customers can only see their area path and nothing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such a feature to limit users in team project level with the area path set.

Area path only restricts the users on work items:

> Area paths allow you to group work items by team, product, or feature
>   area. Whereas, iteration paths allow you to group work into sprints,
>   milestones, or other event-specific or time-related period. Both these
>   fields allow you to define a hierarchy of paths.

Please see [About area and iteration paths (aka sprints)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/about-areas-iterations?view=vsts) for details.

So, if you don't want to the users see the specific team projects, then you just need to remove the users from the related TFS groups.

If you just want to restrict the users on manage the sources/files or source control on specific Repository/branches, then you can create teams or groups and set the permission accordingly. Please see below articles for details:

- [Add teams and team members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/multiple-teams?view=vsts)
- [Permissions and groups in VSTS and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions?view=vsts)

Comment: The problem is that we have teams that work on multiple projects. And we want customers to have access to their projects. As in one team can work on let's say 5 projects in one sprint. How would you go about that in TFS/VSTS

Comment: @TomEsendam If you mean multiple team projects, then you can create a team/group and add the customers to then team/groups of the specific team project. If you mean the develop projects within the same team project, then unfortunately we can not achieve that. we can only restrict them to see the corresponding work items with set the area and iteration path.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly I can make sure that customer X can not see the backlog items and tasks etc from customer Y but I cannot prevent customer X from knowing we have a project running for customer Y?

Comment: @TomEsendam Yes, the areas will be used by teams to determine **what shows up on the team's backlog and what work items the team is responsible for**. But if they create a query against other areas, they can also see other work items.

Comment: @TomEsendam No, the only thing I can think of is managing with **multiple team projects**, that means one develop project under one team project, thus you can add/remove the users accordingly to restrict who can see the specific project.

Comment: Will functionality like this ever be available inside of VSTS/TFS?

Comment: @TomEsendam That's not the common case which TFS/VSTS designed for.  Just as I said, the workaround is managing with multiple team projects. We cannot achieve that if Develop projects within the same team project. However you can submit a user voice to suggest  the feature [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services) .But for now no such a built-in feature.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in this thread, by design a team can access other teams backlogs and work items.

To deny different teams access to other teams work items I used a workaround which might work for you as well.

The workaround is to use TFS security groups to limit teams access to area paths. By default, every team is created as a member of the default security group [project]\Contributors which gives the team access to all area paths.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Create a new security group for every team
2. Make the new groups members of the Contributors default group
3. Add every team as a member of its new respective security group
4. Remove all teams from the Contributors group
5. In the project's areas admin screen, open each area's context menu and click the security option ([check this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#create-child-nodes-modify-work-items-under-an-area-path))
6. In the security view, add the newly created security groups
7. For each group, allow/deny the permissions based on your requirements

Please note, this workaround will not hide other area paths from the users in the not allowed groups. They still can navigate to backlogs of other groups but they will not view or edit the work items. This behavior is same for reports and dashboards as well

Comment: This solution worked for me with TFS 2018 - however with Azure Devops 2019 Server this did not work anymore. As soon as I removed the team from the contributors group, it was not able anymore to access the team project at all.

Comment: To solve it, we had to give the team explicit rights to "View project-level information". Then the team was again able to only see and change items under their area path.